# No drop in mongodb write bandwidth after changing to atomic update

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services

I recently changed how data was being updated in a large mongo collection. The average document size in this collection is 71K.

MongoDB Info:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-1-179 mongodata]$ mongod --version
db version v3.0.7
git version: 6ce7cbe8c6b899552dadd907604559806aa2e9bd
```

Storage Engine: `WiredTiger`

Previously we were retrieving the entire document, adding a single element to 3 arrays and then writing the entire document back to Mongo.

The recent change I made was to create atomic ADD operations so that rather than writing the entire document back to Mongo we just called 3 ADD operations instead.

This has had a considerable impact on the network bandwidth into the mongo server (from 634 MB/s to 72 MB/s average):
[image: Change in Network IN to MongoDB]

But the disk volume metrics tell a VERY different story.

There was absolutely NO change in the data volume metrics (i.e. /var/mongodata/):
[image: Data Volume Metrics]

The journal volume metrics appear to show a significantly INCREASED write bandwidth and IOPS (i.e. /var/mongodata/journal):
[image: Journal Volume Metrics]

I can 'just about' justify the increased journal write IOPS as I am now performing multiple smaller operations instead of one large one.

Here is a current snapshot of mongostat (which doesn't suggest a huge number of inserts or updates)

```
insert query update delete getmore command % dirty % used flushes vsize   res qr|qw ar|aw netIn netOut conn set repl     time
     1   910    412     *0       0    77|0     7.7   80.2       0 29.2G 21.9G   0|0   4|2    1m    55m  738 rs0  PRI 16:21:45
     1   758     19     *0       0    51|0     7.3   80.0       0 29.2G 21.9G   0|1  2|22   82k    29m  738 rs0  PRI 16:21:47
    *0  1075    164     *0       0    83|0     7.4   80.1       0 29.2G 21.9G   0|0   4|2    1m    36m  738 rs0  PRI 16:21:48
    *0  1046    378     *0       0    77|0     7.3   80.1       0 29.2G 21.9G   0|0   4|2  629k    55m  738 rs0  PRI 16:21:49
    *0  1216    167     *0       0    58|0     7.6   80.2       0 29.2G 21.9G   0|1  1|11  238k    43m  738 rs0  PRI 16:21:50
    *0  1002      9     *0       0    59|0     1.1   79.7       1 29.2G 21.9G   0|1  1|22  105k    35m  738 rs0  PRI 16:21:51
    *0   801     37     *0       0   275|0     0.7   79.9       0 29.2G 21.9G   0|2  13|1  949k    17m  738 rs0  PRI 16:21:52
     1  2184    223     *0       0   257|0     0.9   80.1       0 29.2G 21.9G   0|0   3|2  825k    52m  738 rs0  PRI 16:21:53
    *0  1341    128     *0       0   124|0     0.9   80.0       0 29.2G 21.9G   0|1  2|39  706k    55m  738 rs0  PRI 16:21:54
     1  1410    379     *0       0   121|0     1.2   80.0       0 29.2G 21.9G   0|0   2|2    2m    66m  738 rs0  PRI 16:21:55
```

My question is, WHY, given the almost 10 fold drop in network bandwidth (which represent the size of the write operations) is this change not being reflected by the data volume metrics.

Comment: Which mongodb storage engine are you using?

Comment: Mongo v3.0.7, WiredTiger

Comment: IIRC wired tiger always does a full copy - can't find a reference at the moment